# how to set a default loglevel in slf4j logback.xml when an invalid log level is specified

Tags: java, logback, slf4j

is something like the following available ?

```
<logger name="mylogger" level="ERROR" defaultLevel="INFO">
```

So when someone changes the logger configuration in run time with an invalid log level (example: in case of a typo) it should log with loglevel INFO.

Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, ofc you can do this but you need to implement it as so.

here is a code snippet from Log4j which if provided an invalid log will be set to your specified default value

```
public static Level toLevel(int val, Level defaultLevel) {
    switch(val) {
    case -2147483648:
        return ALL;
    case 5000:
        return TRACE;
    case 10000:
        return DEBUG;
    case 20000:
        return INFO;
    case 30000:
        return WARN;
    case 40000:
        return ERROR;
    case 50000:
        return FATAL;
    case 2147483647:
        return OFF;
    default:
        return defaultLevel;
    }
```

Comment: Bad for me I am not at liberty to implement this and have to only rely on logback.xml. I was wondering if logback.xml natively supports a flag or option to set the default level.